# Mac Yosemite shows too large backups

Tags: macos, osx-yosemite

When I open **About this Mac** I see that the backups are 140TB whereas the disk space is only 750 GB

[image]

Why is it so?

How to change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also had the About this Mac window showing incorrect usage info about my disk, but not ridiculously more than my disks capacity like in your case. Either way, try reindexing your disk by running this in Terminal:

```
sudo mdutil -E /
```

After you run it you may need to restart your computer.

**Edit:** Are you running 10.10.3? If so there may be a bug in that version that may cause incorrect space estimates. According to [MacIssues](http://www.macissues.com/2015/04/15/address-available-hard-drive-space-skyrocketing-after-installing-os-x-10-10-3/), you should try disabling local Time Machine backups by running

```
sudo tmutil disablelocal
```

Be aware that this will also delete any local backups on your computer, but it should fix the space estimate issue. You can reenable by running the same command but instead of `disablelocal` use `enablelocal`, although be aware that the issue may reappear if reenabled.

Comment: Disabling time machine and restart solved it. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Also, check what you are PRESENTLY using disk space wise ... Does that semi jive with size of backups remember  mac (and other unix/linux OSes) can use a thin pool or emulated disk  (like they do when installing the OS...